# Installing pyside while i have 2 versions of Python

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, pyside

The docs of Unity say that the package (pyside) doesn't work with Python 3, so i installed Python 2.7. Do i have to uninstall Python  3.8 before trying to install pyside?
Is enough to select 2.7 as the python version by default? (it is marked with a * when i type py --list in the command prompft)

If so, how can i do that? There is a error appearing like this:

-> C:\Users\Usuario>py 2.7
-> C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python3.9.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\Usuario\2.7': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I have installed py 2.7 but i dont know how can i select it and if i need to select it

Comment: This is the manual of installing pyside:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.scripting.python@2.0/manual/installation.html

Comment: Use PySide2/PySide6 with Python3. Do not use PySide/Python2 as they are both obsolete and unsupported legacy libraries.